# How can i get the underscore off my "say_this" in my move_dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, text

```
def get_input():
    move_list = input(": ").split()
    movement = move_list[0]
    if movement in move_dict:
        movement = move_dict[movement]
    else:
        print("wrong answer {}".format(movement))
        return

    if len(move_list) >= 2:
        movement2 = move_list[1]
        print(movement(movement2))
    else:
        print(movement("noting"))

def say_this(noun):
    return "you said {}".format(noun)
```

How to remove the underscore from "say_this" so I could type say this without no underscore in my input?

```
move_dict = {   "say_this": say_this }

while True:
    get_input()
```

Comment: just a simple text adventure game just trying to see how to type in my input and "say this" without no underscore.

Comment: You write `move_dict = { "say this": say_this }` instead? However `split` will split your input at spaces, so that is kind of a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

Assemble *all* pieces of the input, except the last one, in one string defining the type of move:

```
movement = " ".join(move_list[:-1])
```

The argument for the move is now the *last* element, rather than the *second* one:

```
movement2 = move_list[-1]
```

And remove the underscore, of course.

Comment: thank you it works now! anyway you be able to explain on how this method works and why just for me in case I run into this situation again in the future?

Comment: When you type "say this XXX" (without the underscore) and split the input, you get a list of _three_ items: `["say", "this", "XXX"]`. The first two `...[:-1]` are the command which has to be joined back into one string, the last one `...[-1]` is the parameter. You should read about list slicing and joining.